# Redirect when clicked on Swal cancel button but not when clicked outside of Swal

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I've tried to use `result.dismiss`, `result.isDismissed`, and `result.isDenied` but I can't seem to get specific enough to check if the user clicked outside of the swal message.
Here is my code:

```
Swal.fire({
  position: "top-end",
  title: `${name} successfully added to cart!`,
  icon: "success",
  showCancelButton: true,
  cancelButtonText: "Continue shopping",
  cancelButtonColor: "green",
  confirmButtonText: "Go To Cart",
  confirmButtonColor: "blue",
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) history.push("/cart");
  else if (location.pathname == "/" && !result.dismiss)
    history.push("/products");
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Depending on the version you use, Swal provides a "allowOutsideClick" option, I'm not sure if it's related to your problem ?

Comment: It's not related but thank you for your comment :)

Comment: Ok, sorry for the noise lol :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the alert was dismissed using the cancel button by checking if results `.dismiss` reason is equal to [`Swal.DismissReason.cancel`](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#handling-dismissals):

```js
Swal.fire({
  position: "top-end",
  title: "Item successfully added to cart!",
  icon: "success",
  showCancelButton: true,
  cancelButtonText: "Continue shopping",
  cancelButtonColor: "green",
  confirmButtonText: "Go To Cart",
  confirmButtonColor: "blue",
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
    console.log("Redirect for cancel");
  } else {
    console.log("Redirect for non-cancel dismissals");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.0.16/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```